# SQL Server Query syntax to count maximum occurrences of a variable and output same

Tags: sql-server, max

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a simple query that gives me the following output if I run it against the relevant table.
So here's the query:

```
use MyDatabase

select ReservationStayID
       , NonRoomBundleID
       ,StayDate

from ResStayNonRoomBundle

where ReservationStayID = 11676
```

Output is as follows:

```
ReservationStayID   NonRoomBundleID     StayDate
 11676                   2              2014-07-23 00:00:00.000
 11676                   2              2014-07-24 00:00:00.000
 11676                   2              2014-07-25 00:00:00.000
 11676                   2              2014-07-26 00:00:00.000
 11676                   2              2014-07-27 00:00:00.000
 11676                   2              2014-07-28 00:00:00.000
 11676                   4              2014-07-29 00:00:00.000
 11676                   4              2014-07-30 00:00:00.000
 11676                   4              2014-07-31 00:00:00.000
 11676                   4              2014-08-01 00:00:00.000
 11676                   4              2014-08-02 00:00:00.000
 11676                   4              2014-08-03 00:00:00.000
 11676                   4              2014-08-04 00:00:00.000
 11676                   1              2014-08-05 00:00:00.000
```

Now, I need to modify my query to get the following output:

```
ReservationStayID   NonRoomBundle ID    MTH

       11676            2               July 2014
       11676            4               August 2014
```

And this is what I did:

```
USE MyDatabase
select ReservationStayID,max(NonRoomBundleID) AS [NonRoomBundle  ID],datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar) as  [MTH] 

from ResStayNonRoomBundle

where ReservationStayID = 11676

group by datename(m,StayDate) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,StayDate) as varchar), ReservationStayID
```

and it is giving me the following output:

```
ReservationStayID   NonRoomBundle ID    MTH
       11676            4               July 2014
       11676            4               August 2014
```

I need to change that max(NonRoomBundleID) into a logic that outputs the 'NonRoomBundleID' with the maximum occurences rather than just the MAXIMUM value.

In other words, I want the query to count the maximum occurrences of the NonRoomBundleID for each month and output that one. In the case of July 2014, NonRoomBundleID which has the most occurences is 2. So, I want the query to output 2 as a result for July 2014.

May be using a COUNT function? If yes, how do I implement it into my existing query?

Comment: How can you get the numbers 2 and 4 from that data? Doesn't seem that clear.

Comment: @James. I am not getting 2 and 4. I am getting 4 and 4. In fact, I want the output to be 2 and 4

Comment: I want the query to count the maximum occurences of the NonRoomBundleID for each month and output that one. In the case of July 2014, NonRoomBundleID 2 has the most occurences. So, I want the query to output 2 as a result for July 2014.

Comment: `GROUP BY` month and reservation ID, then `COUNT` the number of same NonRoomBundleIDs. Wrap that in another `SELECT` for the `MAX` of the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  ReservationStayID, NonRoombundleID, Tot, 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(month,  M,'1970-1-1')))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(month, DATEADD(month,  M,'1970-1-1'))) AS [Month] 
FROM 
   (
    SELECT ReservationStayID, NonRoombundleID, COUNT(*) AS Tot,   
     DATEDIFF(month, '1970-1-1', staydate) m, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             partition by ReservationStayID, 
             DATEDIFF(month, '1970-1-1', staydate)  
             ORDER BY Count(*) DESC
             )  AS rownum
     FROM ResStayNonRoomBundle
     GROUP BY ReservationStayID, NonRoombundleID,
             DATEDIFF(month, '1970-1-1', staydate) 
    )  
    e 
 WHERE rownum =1
```

To use your own month format:

```
SELECT  ReservationStayID, NonRoombundleID, Tot, 
   datename(m,DATEADD(MONTH, M, '1970-1-1')) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,DATEADD(MONTH, M,'1970-1-1')) as varchar)
FROM 
   (
    SELECT ReservationStayID, NonRoombundleID, COUNT(*) AS Tot,   
     DATEDIFF(month, '1970-1-1', staydate) m, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by ReservationStayID, DATEDIFF(month, '1970-1-1', staydate)  order by Count(*) DESC)  As rownum
     FROM ResStayNonRoomBundle
     GROUP BY ReservationStayID, NonRoombundleID, DATEDIFF(month, '1970-1-1', staydate) 
    ) 
    e 
 WHERE rownum =1
```

If you want to list all top spots in each month, try this:

```
SELECT  ReservationStayID, NonRoombundleID, Tot, 
   datename(m,DATEADD(MONTH, M, '1970-1-1')) + ' ' + cast(datepart(yyyy,DATEADD(MONTH, M,'1970-1-1')) as varchar) [Month]
FROM 
   (
    SELECT ReservationStayID, NonRoombundleID, COUNT(*) AS Tot,   
     DATEDIFF(month, '1970-1-1', staydate) m
     FROM ResStayNonRoomBundle L
     GROUP BY ReservationStayID, NonRoombundleID, DATEDIFF(month, '1970-1-1', staydate) 
     HAVING COUNT(*) = (
        SELECT MAX(Tot) FROM  (
           SELECT COUNT(*) AS Tot 
           FROM ResStayNonRoomBundle T
           WHERE DATEDIFF(month, '1970-1-1', T.staydate)  = DATEDIFF(month, '1970-1-1', L.staydate) 
           GROUP BY ReservationStayID, NonRoombundleID
           ) c
        )
     )
    e 
ORDER BY m
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but is it possible to modify your query so that the MTH remains in the format of my query? Just asking because I will need to do a  JOIN using that Month column in another query.

Comment: Sure. I changed the answers

Comment: I have a small question though....what happens when the NonRoomBundleID is equally split in terms of occurrences. Say, for July 2014, we had 3 occurrences with number 4 and 3 occurrences with number 5.

Comment: You need decide how to proceed if there are multiple choices for the top spot, currently it returns the first one. If you want to list all those on the top spot, the query has to be changed.

Comment: In case there are equal number of occurrences, I just want it to list the top 1. So I guess it still stands good.